# PHP Flexible Access Control

Tags: php, security, access-control

I need to find a flexible solution for access control in PHP. In the past I have created a mapping between pages and the minimum access level required, and that has worked well in cases where access levels have been clear cut and hierarchical. I am working on a project now where I still need access control, but without the luxury of clear cut hierarchical access levels.

Basically, we have a site which we want to allow our customers to brand as their own using custom templates. Each site will have the exact same pages, but individual sites may have between 1 and 4 access levels, and there is no clearly defined hierarchy that the pages may fit in to which can be used to define permissions.

I found some documentation for a library called [Flaxis](http://code.google.com/p/flaxis/), which looked really good, but unfortunately the library itself seems to be missing.

Does anyone have any experience with a library which can meet my needs, or have any ideas for how I might handle these flexible permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, sometimes the best solution is to just build it yourself. I ended up creating and open-sourcing [PHP-Bouncer](https://code.google.com/p/php-bouncer/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html/) as a standalone component just include the code and use it

Comment: Zend_Acl does access control, but it is quite a naive implementation. Also, where it says 'roles' it should actually read 'usergroup' or 'authorisation profile'. (I've just completed an analysis of this library for our company, based on what we found, we decided not to use it.)

Comment: I briefly looked at the Documentation, but have not yet found enough data to make a decision. @Jacco, Did you find anything else worth checking out?

Comment: I think Zend_Acl fits most needs but obviously Jacco seems to have a lot more expertise in the field.Have you look to yii access control?

Comment: @BrendonDugan, For the not-too-complex applications, Zend_Acl probably Ok-enough. We've decided to build an pRBAC library based on the NIST RBAC standard, with parametrisation as by Sylvia L. Osborn's model. For an intermediate solution take a look at [phpGACL](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/) and try to avoid negative permissions. (Negative permissions lead to all sorts of unexpected edge-cases)

Comment: It looks like some of the solutions on the web are good, but none of them are great. Therefore I've decided to just roll my own, open-source style. I've created a project called PHP-Bouncer on Google Code ( https://code.google.com/p/php-bouncer/ ), and I would love any input anyone has for the project. @Jacco, I would love to hear more about the edge cases you've experienced with the negative permissions. Perhaps you'll join the project?

Comment: @BrendonDugan, our pRBAC library will be open-sourced when it meets the requirements and specifications. Until then, I'll see if I can comment on your Google code project.

Comment: @BrendonDugan, is there a discussion area somewhere on the google code pages?

Comment: @Jacco: I'm still trying to find one. If you feel like discussing outside of SO, you can find my email address on the DevFAQ at http://code.google.com/p/php-bouncer/wiki/DevFAQ and from there I can add you to the project if you want.

Comment: @Jacco, in the mean time, here is a google group for php-bouncer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/php-bouncer-discussion